# Microsoft Access odbc problem on new windows server 2008

Tags: ms-access, windows-server-2008

I've got a client that I wrote an asp front end application 2 yrs ago, which connects to a access 2007 database.  All the files sat on a windows server 2000 machine 2 yrs ago.  They recently upgraded their server to a windows server 2008 machine (64bit).  Now the asp can't connect to the Access database via the ODBC connection.  I tried using a dsnless connection, as well as, a manually created dsn connection (the manual dsn was created on the server 2008 machine using the 32bit .exe wizard to create dsn connections)...but that didn't work.  I get an error that basically says the database odbc couldn't connect.

I've read that this is a problem between a 64bit 2008 server and a 32bit application (access 2007), but I can't seem to find any solutions to fix this problem.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, or offer some help?  I'm really clueless how to solve this for them and they really don't have any other people to help.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have seen similar issues when running asp applications in 64 bit mode in IIS. Could this be the case?

Comment: yes, thats exactly the case.  Any ideas what to do?

Answer (score 2):

On a Windows 2008 x64 the following can be done to enable 32 bit applications in IIS:

- Open IIS (inetmgr command)
- Locate the application pool that your application is using
- In the pool's advanced settings, set Enable 32-bit Applications to true

If that doesn't work, try enabling 32 bit compatibility mode by using the following command:

`cscript c:\inetpub\adminscripts\adsutil.vbs SET /w3svc/AppPools/Enable32BitAppOnWin64 True`

Hope it helps!